# Remix App - Error: Minified React error #418 / #423 - on Google Analytics gtag script

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, server-side-rendering, remix.run, gtag.js

I have a remix App (SSR). When i add a script for google analytics, it shows an error of hydration in production , especially on line with `gtag('js', new Date())`
Does anybody know another way to add this script, or remove this error?

[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r86uT.jpg)

i tried adding `suppressHydrationWarning={true}` but still have error message

Comment: The really nice thing about those React errors is that they provide you a link to documentation that includes details about the issue/error and it provides suggestions/solutions to resolve them.